# How to replace returned column value in SQL SELECT query?

Tags: sql, database, select, oracle10g

I'm unsure exactly how to name the title, so sorry in advance.

Anyway, I have the following SQL SELECT query (Oracle) to search for specific statuses of requests:

```
SELECT ib.incident_id,
       ib.incident_status_id
  FROM cs_incidents_all_b ib, cs_incidents_all_tl it
  WHERE ib.incident_id = it.incident_id
   AND ib.incident_status_id IN (
    SELECT st.incident_status_id
      FROM cs_incident_statuses_tl st
      WHERE st.NAME IN
             ('Accept Order',
              'Order Accepted',
              'Address Retrieved',
              'Analyze',
              'Entered',
              'Information Retrieved',
              'Retrieve Address',
              'Retrieve Information',
              'Returned'));
```

Currently, when running this query, I get the following output in the last column (**incident_status_id**): 103

This number is a key in the **cs_incident_statuses_tl** table, and in that table, there's a column namned **name** that has a clear-text string, in this case 'Analyze'.

How can the SELECT query above be modified so when it is run, the return does not show 103 but 'Analyze' instead? I've tried experimenting with various JOINs, but I haven't found a good way to present the clear-text description instead.

Any help is very appreciated, thanks in advance! Sorry if the question's stupid, SQL is far from my forte. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cs_incidents_all_tl is not use in your query, I remove it in this query:

```
SELECT ib.incident_id,
   ib.incident_status_id,
   st.NAME
FROM cs_incidents_all_b ib
INNER JOIN cs_incident_statuses_tl st ON st.incident_status_id=ib.incident_status_id
WHERE st.NAME IN
         ('Accept Order',
          'Order Accepted',
          'Address Retrieved',
          'Analyze',
          'Entered',
          'Information Retrieved',
          'Retrieve Address',
          'Retrieve Information',
          'Returned'));
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit clumsy,but try

```
SELECT ib.incident_id,
       ib.incident_status_id,
       (    SELECT st.NAME
            FROM cs_incident_statuses_tl st
            WHERE st.incident_status_id = ib.incident_status_id
       ) StatusName
  FROM cs_incidents_all_b ib, cs_incidents_all_tl it
  WHERE ib.incident_id = it.incident_id
   AND ib.incident_status_id IN (
    SELECT st.incident_status_id
      FROM cs_incident_statuses_tl st
      WHERE st.NAME IN
             ('Accept Order',
              'Order Accepted',
              'Address Retrieved',
              'Analyze',
              'Entered',
              'Information Retrieved',
              'Retrieve Address',
              'Retrieve Information',
              'Returned'));
```